# How do I clear all variables in node REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I open a REPL on my terminal with `node` or `node -i`.

After playing around, I’d like to clear everything in this REPL (chiefly the JS variables that I created). Is there a command to do that? I currently use `.exit` followed by `node`, but I’d like to do it without closing and reopening the REPL, and the `.clear` command does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about creating a new REPLServer instance?

```sh
$ node -r repl -e "repl.start()"
> const x = 'hello';
undefined
> .clear
Clearing context...
> x
Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

REPLServer is customizable. See this reference: https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html .

Comment: That’s a very nice way. I suppose that with a bash alias, it would work perfectly!

Comment: It seems that `node -e "repl.start()"` is enough to have the `.clear` command working, what is the purpose of loading the repl module?

Comment: I just didn't know that repl module loads implicitly. You can remove `-r repl`. Thanks.

Comment: I created an alias in `~/.zshrc`: `alias n='node -e "repl.start()"'` and it works perfectly, thanks!